# How do I get Windows 10 Terminal to launch WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I'm using the new Windows Terminal, and trying to get it to launch my WSL terminal. This is the setting that I'm trying to use:

```
        {
            "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75,
            "closeOnExit" : true,
            "colorScheme" : "Campbell",
            "commandline" : "%LOCALAPPDATA%/wsltty/bin/mintty.exe --WSL= --configdir='%APPDATA%/wsltty' -~ ",
            "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
            "cursorShape" : "bar",
            "fontFace" : "Consolas",
            "fontSize" : 10,
            "guid" : "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
            "historySize" : 9001,
            "icon" : "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}.png",
            "name" : "wsl",
            "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
            "snapOnInput" : true,
            "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%",
            "useAcrylic" : true
        }
```

But all it's doing is opening some sort of CMD.

What's the correct command to run the WSL terminal

**Edit:**

I did notice that the GUID was the same thing as the regular CMD, so I changed that. Then it did launch an *external* shell.

Comment: You can use the https://github.com/nateshmbhat/windows-terminal-tweaker
windows terminal tweaker to configure the terminal pretty easily.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You need to do following things first.

**1. Install Linux (e.g. Ubuntu)**

Search "Ubuntu" in the Microsoft store, then buy and install. This is actually WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

[image: 1557633269919]

Of course, you want to experience other versions of Linux, as well as Debian:

[image: 1557633347262]

**2. Enable WSL permissions**

After installing the WSL version of Linux, you also need to enable WSL permissions:

Open another PowerShell window with "Run as Administrator".

[image: 1557633727047]

Then enter the following command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

[image: 1557633836814]

After the command is completed, you can execute the Linux command in the built-out Terminal.

First enter `ubuntu` in cmd, take a little time to start Ubuntu, set the username and password.

Then you can play with Ubuntu happily. Below I entered a few common commands such as `ps`, `touch`, `ls` etc., as shown below.

[image: 1557633540178]

**3. Change settings**

Click "Settings" in right top corner of above image, the file `profile.json` file will be opened. Then inside the word `"profiles"` in `profile.json` file, add below snippet.

```
        {
            "guid": "{78e390db-1bff-4533-9d7c-20f53d8bafa1}",
            "name": "WSL",
            "colorscheme": "Campbell",
            "historySize": 9001,
            "snapOnInput": true,
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cursorShape": "bar",
            "commandline": "wsl ~",
            "fontFace": "Consolas",
            "fontSize": 12,
            "acrylicOpacity": 0.75,
            "useAcrylic": true,
            "closeOnExit": false,
            "padding": "0, 0, 0, 0"
        }
```

Near the word `"schemes"` in `profile.json` file, you need to update below:

```
"schemes": [
        {
            "name": "Campbell",
            "foreground": "#A7B191", 
            "background": "#0C0C0C",
            "colors": [
                "#0C0C0C",
                "#C50F1F",
                "#13A10E",
                "#C19C00",
                "#0037DA",
                "#881798",
                "#3A96DD",
                "#CCCCCC",
                "#767676",
                "#E74856",
                "#16C60C",
                "#F9F1A5",
                "#3B78FF",
                "#B4009E",
                "#61D6D6",
                "#F2F2F2"
            ]
        }
```

The complete setting file (profile.json) which can be obtained [here](https://github.com/yanglr/WindowsDevTools/blob/master/awosomeTerminal/profile-my.json).

Actually, the WSL here is Ubuntu.

**4. Add icons to different types of tabs**

You can add icons for Tab to this location:

```
 %LOCALAPPDATA%\packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\RoamingState
```

I put some 32x32 PNG in this folder, and then in `profile.json` I can reference the image resource with the path starting with `ms-appdata://` .

The icon is available here: 
[Icons](https://github.com/yanglr/WindowsDevTools/tree/master/awosomeTerminal/icons)

Then replace the contents of the new `profile-withIcons.json` file below with the previous settings. 
[profile-withIcons.json](https://github.com/yanglr/WindowsDevTools/blob/master/awosomeTerminal/profile-withIcons.json)

After finishing the contents of the folder is like this:

[image: Dir]

The final result is:

[image: Icons]

Comment: @Wayne Werner FYI.

Comment: Very thorough! Nice!

Comment: The correct path for an icon in `RoamingState` is actually: `ms-appdata:///roaming/{filename}`

Comment: @BravoYeung, thanks for detailed answer.... but how to find guid?

Comment: @Psychozoic make sure that you assigned a GUID string to each item in the profile file and each GUID is unique. You can use Visual Studio to generate the unique GUID, no need to find in somewhere else.

Comment: @BravoYeung i found, that on that profile.json there is no need to find guid in system. Any random number will work (which created by format).
so, no need to use any generator at all.

Comment: Or just install wsl2 and type `wsl` in a cmd?

Answer (score 34):

To launch any distribution, you can also use this for commandline:

```
wsl.exe -d <name_of_the_distribution>
```

Like :

```
wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-18.04
```

You can list all distributions with :

```
wsl.exe -l
```

.

PS : Tux icon for Linux :

```
ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{9acb9455-ca41-5af7-950f-6bca1bc9722f}.png
```

Comment: Is there a way to open a instance of wsl.exe in a new terminal window?

Comment: Tried cmd.exe /c start wsl.exe -c ls but terminal window closes as soon as it opens

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was very confused with why `wsl.exe -d bash` wasn't executing previously when I tried it after seeing the command elsewhere, it makes sense now.

Comment: As of Windows 11, setting a terminal profile to launch `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu` seems to give you a shell at `/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32` which is not the best starting point. You can instead get a shell at the Linux home directory by setting it to launch `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu --cd ~`.

Answer (score 8):

Recent versions of Windows Terminal include support for [Dynamic Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles), in which new WSL distros will automatically be added to the list of available profiles.

[image: Screenshot of Windows Terminal with WSL profile added]

However, if Windows Terminal is running when you install the new distro, it will not currently get added while running. You must exit and re-start Windows Terminal, and the new profile will automatically appear.

Once it is added, you can edit/move it using the Settings dialog or by editing `settings.json` as usual. Each WSL distro is identified using a GUID which will have been auto-populated.

[image: Screenshot of settings.json being edited in Notepad++]

As described in the linked article, Dynamic Profiles can be turned off by disabling their source(s) such as the following in `settings.json`:

```json
"disabledProfileSources": ["Windows.Terminal.Wsl", "Windows.Terminal.Azure", "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore"]
```

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that all I needed to do was change the commandline to `ubuntu1804.exe`. Like this:

```
        {
            "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75,
            "closeOnExit" : true,
            "colorScheme" : "Campbell",
            "commandline": "ubuntu1804.exe",
            "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
            "cursorShape" : "bar",
            "fontFace" : "Consolas",
            "fontSize" : 10,
            "guid" : "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-abceeeaa6101}",
            "historySize" : 9001,
            "icon" : "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}.png",
            "name" : "wsl",
            "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
            "snapOnInput" : true,
            "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%",
            "useAcrylic" : false
        }
```

Comment: If you have multiple distributions, you can list them with `wsl --list`, and then specify the specific distribution with `wsl --distribution Ubuntu-18.04`, in my case, for the `commandline` parameter.

Answer (score 7):

While my answer is off-question (since answered by the O.P.) I found this question while searching for adding a Windows Terminal (WT) profile for my recent Ubuntu installation, since I had recently re-imaged my laptop.

Updated 19/10/03: Installation order does not matter. My profile for “ubuntu” appears after installing ubuntu, and then launching the ubuntu instance in PowerShell and establish my user account and password. THEN Windows Terminal adds the appropriate shell profile for WSL.

Comment: It does not add it to the main configuration though. Terminal app picks up this distro is installed from somewhere else

Comment: thank you so much! that is exactly what I was looking for. I was kinda disappointed that opening a new Linux tab didn't grant me access to its directories properly.

EDIT: what I do is: 

1. launch Windows Terminal 

2. run the command for my distro of choice, eg. ubuntu2004.exe

3. profit

Answer (score 6):

1. Open settings

[image: Open Settings]

2. Change the "Default Profile" in the drop down.

[image: Change the Default Profile]

3. Click "Save" on the bottom right.

Answer (score 5):

I have developed a tool for tweaking the terminal configurations here:

[Windows Terminal Tweaker](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/windows-terminal-tweaker)

It lets you add different profiles, gives color pickers to choose color schemes and provides options to tweak every single thing while applying the settings live.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new profile in the windows terminal settings and select the following command line

```
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04
```

where -d selects the distribution to be run.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Terminal allows you to open the settings and change things there. If you already have ubuntu installed, it should be an option to set the ubuntu profile as your default config.

Copy paste the guid for ubuntu into the defaultProfile and it will automatically launch WSL ubuntu instead of powershell by default.

Comment: This is now the best up-to-date answer.

In all my reading and scrolling I did not notice the key at the top called `defaultProfile`.

Simply scroll down, locate the block for your WSL (or whatever), copy the `guid` and paste it in as the key for the `defaultProfile`.

Restart Terminal; Done ...

Answer (score 3):

*The premise of the question was fouled by the mistake with the `GUID`, as the OP says the sample code was actually correct. So, the question could be re-interpreted as--*

#### *What is the minimum required change to the default settings.json to point to an application of your choosing?* (which is what got me here)

1. `guid` - has to be unique. I've had success with changing just the last number for each customization.
2. `commandline` - From within Bravo Yeung's answer is a link to a [sample settings.json file](https://github.com/yanglr/WindowsDevTools/blob/master/awosomeTerminal/profile-my.json): `"commandline": "wsl ~"`

This little bitty value is made possible by setting a [default distro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#managing-multiple-linux-distributions): *"The default WSL distribution is the one that runs when you run wsl on a command line:"*

`wsl --setdefault <DistributionName>`

**However**, seems `commandline:wsl` doesn't work with `startingDirectory`.
I've successfully omitted `commandline` in favor of `source` + `startingDirectory`:

```
// Make changes here to the cmd.exe profile.
"guid": "{long-guid-here}",
"hidden": false,
"name": "Debian",
"tabTitle" : "WSL (Debian)",
"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
"startingDirectory" : "C:\\Users\\myuser"
```

Here is a good link which got me started the first time I installed Windows Terminal and customized the settings, [Easily add Anaconda Prompt to Windows Terminal to make life better](https://dev.to/azure/easily-add-anaconda-prompt-in-windows-terminal-to-make-life-better-3p6j)

Answer (score 0):

Just start windows terminal, powershell, then type "debian" or whatever distro installed. This automatically both adds it to windows terminal, tux and all,  and open a new tab with wsl.