# How to add WSL-Ubuntu shell to Github Desktop shells list?

Tags: github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, github-desktop

I want to use `WSL-Ubuntu-Shell` in the `GitHub desktop app`. In the `Desktop App for GitHub`, there is only `Powershell`, `cmd`, and `Git Bash`. How to add `WSL-Ubuntu-Shell`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to install the [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701), which is [available](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/pull/9047) as a shell option in GitHub Desktop.

You can then set up Windows Terminal to open WSL. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56765067/5987698) explains how.

---

The shell integration [documentation](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/4640bb6a750c776cfa644f734cace513eced4e2f/docs/technical/shell-integration.md) of GitHub Desktop mentions that support for WSL is now available in the beta version. Alternatively, the docs also explain how to add a shell of your choice by modifying the code appropriately.

Comment: I know how to install Windows Terminal and WSL, but It doesn't appear in the list of Github Desktop App Shells

Comment: @NaveedHematmal It's odd that Windows Terminal does not appear -- is your GitHub Desktop version recent enough? The feature seems to have been added only 2 months ago.

Comment: I have updated the app, now `Windows terminal` has been added there, but still I can't find Ubuntu (Ubuntu in WSL)

Comment: @NaveedHematmal My suggestion was to launch WSL Ubuntu through Windows Terminal (which is explained in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765067/how-do-i-get-windows-10-terminal-to-launch-wsl ). Works for me. I just searched a bit more, and [this doc](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/4640bb6a750c776cfa644f734cace513eced4e2f/docs/technical/shell-integration.md) says that WSL integration is now available in GitHub Desktop Beta, so you could try that out.

Comment: @NaveedHematmal Alternatively, that doc also explains how to add your own preferred shell by tweaking the code a bit.