# How to add wsl command line arguments to Windows Terminal configuration?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I have the following .json configuration for my Windows Terminal:

```
        {
            "guid": "{926758ba-8c4a-5c36-a9c6-0c4943cd78a1}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Fedora-33",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"
        },
```

This was generated automatically from the WSL database.

I would like to add wsl command line option `-u user` as it starts now as root. I tried adding

```
            "user" : "hxv454"
```

to no avail. How can I configure WT to start my wsl instance with a specific user?

Answer (score 1):

Learning from

[How do I get Windows 10 Terminal to launch WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765067/how-do-i-get-windows-10-terminal-to-launch-wsl)

searching for "wsl" I have found and used

```
"commandline": "wsl -d Fedora-33 -u hxv454"
```

and it worked.