# launch: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, powershell, typo3

I followed the documentation to install typo3: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/Installation/TutorialDdev.html

I get a error when i use ddev launch command

```
PS t3exemple> ddev launch public/typo3/install.php
/bin/bash: t3exemple\.ddev\.global_commands\host\launch: No such file or directory
```

I decided to type this command: `ddev typo3cms install:setup`

And now how can i launch typo3 ?

Comment: You are using a bash shell so you are running on Linux.  On Linux path separators are forward slashes not backslashes.

Comment: @jdweng The command I typed already uses the "/". This is the error message that shows me the path with the "\"

Comment: Which version of Ddev, and which Shell do you actually run? The output seems odd, as if a very vital ddev command ("launch") doesn't exist. Also, you use Docker or something else with ddev?

Comment: Read System Requirements : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html#system-requirements

Comment: @GarvinHicking For ddev installation i follow this guide https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/install/ddev-installation/#windows *WSL2 + Docker Desktop Install Script*

**ddev --version: v1.22.4**

Comment: @dia05 - if you installed ddev in wsl2, you need to utilize a Bash/Terminal to be "within" WSL2. Using Powershell, you are in the "windows context" instead of "wsl context". There ddev cannot execute commands it can execute if its in the wsl (which means: linux environment). You should have a seperate shell for that...?

Comment: @GarvinHicking How can i use a Bash/Terminal to be "within" WSL2 ? How can i enter in wsl context ?

Comment: Maybe you can search the web for "use terminal in windows wsl" or something like that. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765067/how-do-i-get-windows-10-terminal-to-launch-wsl which has a nice answer with screenshots. Depending on the WSL installation you selected, you might be able to just enter "ubuntu" in your powershell to launch the ubuntu shell...?